# Naming convention for column names

Tags: r, notation

I have a general question. Is there any rule or convention about how to name columns in general (CSV, R, relational databases and so on)?.

If I need to be more specific, I would like to know for R. I am currently using the style guide made by Google ([here](https://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/Rguide.xml)) and it does not mention anything regarding this.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't know of one. Moreover, I'm not sure on what basis such a convention would rest. At any rate, this question is off topic here.

Comment: It's not entirely clear to me that this question is off topic.  However, almost all conventions I am aware of that have any kind of general following are determined by the software: specifically, its lexical and syntactic processing of the input as well as the physical and logical formats of its native files. Certain characters are often ruled out--spaces are common--because their use in programs or commands can be ambiguous. If you are asking a question that might be of use in statistical analysis, could you edit this post to make that connection more explicit?

Comment: Your answer was of great help. My question was related to the actual string and its format (such as avoiding spaces, like you mentioned).

The particular reason why I asked this is because I have seen in some R code, that sometimes people name the columns of a data frame using dots, for example first.name and sometimes, underscore, like first_name. However, in the Google code convention that do talk about using dot for variables, but I was wondering if this also applies to the columns.

Thanks.